# Nested Single.flatMap in RxJava vs Single.zip, are the same?

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm facing a confusion, giving by example 4 Single:

```java
val s1 : Single<String> = service1.execute().subscribeOn(io())
val s2 : Single<Int> = service2.execute().subscribeOn(io())
val s3 : Single<Int> = service3.execute().subscribeOn(io())
val s4 : Single<String> = service4.execute().subscribeOn(io())
val ....
val s10 : Single<Int> = service10.execute().subscribeOn(io())
```

data class MyObj (
  field1: String,
  field2: Int,
  field3: Int,
  field4: String...
  .... 
  field10: Int 
)

and I have a `service10.execute(s1 : String s2 : Int s3 : Int s4 : String)`

If I do:

```java
s1.flatMap { str -> 
    s2.flatMap { int1 ->
        s3.flatMap { int2 ->
            s4.flatMap { str2 ->
                ...
                s10.flatmap { int10
                  service10.execute(myObj(str, int1, int2, str2..., int10))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the same as doing:

```java
Single.zip(
            listOf(
                s1,
                s2,
                s3,
                s4
              ...,
              ...,
              s10
            )
        ) { array ->
            val str = array[0] as String
            val int1 = array[1] as Int
            val int2 = array[2] as Int
            val str2 = array[3] as String
            ...
            val str10 = array[9] as Int
        }
```

1) Is the flatMap executing there in parallel o sequentially there? 
2) If the nested flatMap are sequential, is there a way to make them parallel like the zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the nested `flatMap`s do not make the `Single`s run in parallel, as proved by the following test:

```
    // so we can be sure service1 and service2 are active
    val bothSubscribed = CountDownLatch(2)
    // so we can simulate a blocking, long running operation on both services
    val subscribeThreadsStillRunning = CountDownLatch(1)

    val service5 = { str: String, str2: String ->
        Observable.just("service5: $str, $str2").singleOrError()
    }

    val scheduler = Schedulers.io()

    val createSingle = { value: String ->
        Observable
            .create<String> { emitter ->
                println("subscribe $value on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                bothSubscribed.countDown()
                subscribeThreadsStillRunning.await(10, SECONDS)
                emitter.onNext(value)
            }
            .singleOrError()
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    }

    val s1 = createSingle("outer")
    val s4 = createSingle("inner")

    s1.flatMap { outer ->
        s4.flatMap { inner ->
            service5(outer, inner)
        }
    }.subscribe()

    assert(bothSubscribed.await(5, SECONDS))
    subscribeThreadsStillRunning.countDown()
```

The reason can be understood by remembering that code within lambda's is not run until the lambda is executed (seems obvious saying like that, but it took me a bit of thinking to get it). `s4.flatMap` is what triggers the subscribe to `s4`, but this code doesn't execute until `outer` is available, i.e. until `s1` has already emitted and is therefore complete.

Zip seems like the perfect solution for this, and I'm not sure why you want to use flat map. I can't think of a way to do it. It also has a type safe API so you don't have to use the array based API in your example.

```
Singles
        .zip(s1, s4) { outer, inner -> service5(outer, inner) }
        .flatMap { it }
        .subscribe()
```

Note that I have used `Singles` from `"io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0-RC1"` as the lambdas work better with Kotlin.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721701/flatzip-in-rxjava for flatZip discussion